# functools: computing inter quartile range

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, percentile, functools

I use `functools` to compute percentiles this way:

```
import functools
percentiles = tuple(functools.partial(np.percentile, q=q) for q in (75, 85, 95))

percentiles
(functools.partial(<function percentile at 0x7f91fe1e9730>, q=75),
 functools.partial(<function percentile at 0x7f91fe1e9730>, q=85),
 functools.partial(<function percentile at 0x7f91fe1e9730>, q=95))
```

so that anywhere in my code I can compute percentiles like so:

```
stat_functions =  percentiles
```

Then I want to add inter quartile to my percentile function, but adding [75-25] compute the mean instead.

```
percentiles = tuple(functools.partial(np.percentile, q=q) for q in (75, 85, 95, 75-25))

percentiles
(functools.partial(<function percentile at 0x7f91fe1e9730>, q=75),
 functools.partial(<function percentile at 0x7f91fe1e9730>, q=85),
 functools.partial(<function percentile at 0x7f91fe1e9730>, q=95),
 functools.partial(<function percentile at 0x7f91fe1e9730>, q=50))
```

My intention is to get the value of inter quartile range not the mean. How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to do it like that, but I posted a couple of options.

Comment: I see you've already chosen one. Delayed on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an [`iqr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.iqr.html) function to `scipy.stats` a while back.

You can modify the comprehension as follows:

```
percentiles = tuple(ss.iqr if q is None else functools.partial(np.percentile, q=q) for q in (75, 85, 95, None))
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the IQR with a single call to `percentile`: it's the difference between two percentiles. The closest you can do is to compute the 25th and 75th percentile in one call:

```
functools.partial(np.percentile, q=(25, 75))
```

You can modify your comprehension to construct a function wrapped in `np.diff` when `q` is a tuple:

```
percentiles = tuple(lambda x: np.diff(np.percentile(x, q=q)) if isinstance(q, tuple) else functools.partial(np.percentile, q=q) for q in (75, 85, 95, (25, 75)))
```